# Windows 8.1 boot error after restarting

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, repair

I restarted my notebook after it lagged especially hard thinking it needs a fresh reset. After that it won't boot anymore.

It says "the boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors"

File:EFI\Microsoft\boot\BCD
Error code:0xc0000001

I know that a question with a similar error is present but it's unsolved and our specificity is quite different as I have not dabbled in partitioning.

I did a memory test to make sure RAM isn't the problem as is stated when I googled and the test passed. However I could not test the drive as I would need another HP tool for it.

Anyways my first choice was easyre as it is the first search result but as it turns out I cannot download without payment.

So I googled for a free bootable repair tool and burned that on a flash drive. I was able to boot into it and was just starting to repair but when I did, unfortunately, it turns out I have to pay for the service.

My question is, is there a FREE, reliable, and newbie friendly bootable repair tool for windows 8.1 boot error? I tried searching but I don't think it's 100% matching what I need.

Comment: To answer your question. There is no "repair tool for Windows boot error", every boot error is different, and every case might have a different cause. So the troubleshooting for this is a process, and not a simple tool to run and have it fixed.

Comment: So do you recommend I just go to a repair shop?

Comment: If you do not have any experience with things like this, likely yes.

Comment: But if I never start then I never will. It's 2023  there ought to be smart tools that would help fix problems like these without the hassle of the past.

Comment: So start by understanding this sequence of events is highly indicative of a failed drive exactly as answered. In this cases *always* test the drive from outside of the OS, with any bootable media containing a proper tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the hard disk drive (HDD) is failing (I presume HDD, because 8.1 is so old). The boot information is on the HDD, and the HDD has lost it.

Though you can *possibly* put the boot info back on the drive, i.e., "repair" it, likely it will not *stay* repaired and fail again. If you can, check the S.M.A.R.T. disk data to be sure, e.g., with *free* [Hiren's BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/).

However [Windows 8.1 end of support was Jan 9, 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-81), five years ago (unless you paid for extended support, ending *this year*). Switch to a newer, safer OS, such as Windows 10 or 11, or Linux. For example, you can [run Ubuntu from a USB flash drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started), without replacing the failing HDD, to see if you understand and like it; there is *no* cost for the OS.

Comment: And with the Ubuntu live session you can also check the drive (Disks tool). I second your hypotheses of a failing drive ("lagged especially hard" followed by boot errors strongly suggests that) and also the recommendation about using a supported OS version).

Comment: My drive is actually SSD which is why I cannot test it as it requires another HP tool.

Comment: I can access the drive itself after booting into a bootable drive. Idk if that means it's okay.

Comment: My notebook is only 8.1 because it has 2gb ram and 30gb storage. Upgrading beyond would render it useless as it would be at Max capacity for anything else.

Comment: It came with windows 8.

Comment: No, you don't need any HP tool to test drives, HDDs or SSDs. I actually suggested one in the first comment. And again, this answer suggests **running Ubuntu from a USB flash drive AKA "live session"** and that means absolutely NO change to the hardware. Test the drive and act accordingly. If it fails then don't bother installing anything. of course. At that point decide whether it makes financial sense to replace the SSD only and install e.g. a light Ubuntu variant (Lubuntu) or SSD+RAM and install a supported Windows version or buy another machine. Keep using 8.1 is NOT an option, period.

Comment: You state, "it has 2gb ram and 30gb storage." That is simply not enough to run Windows. The OS creates *many* GB of files in the Windows directory, alone. Try Linux, which *can* fit on a minimal machine. See https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/, for example. Though I fully agree with keeping old systems running (I maintain a 32-bit Acer D250!), don't saddle them with an unusable OS.